# c# 'invalid decimal constant' cannot be converted to a 'double' in Monodroid (Xamarin)

Tags: c#, xamarin.android, decimal, xamarin

I'm trying to convert the decimal.MinValue to its double representation without any success, the compiler returns the 'invalid decimal constant' error with compilation failure.

------------- UPDATE :

The line thats doesn't compile is :

> if (value < (double)decimal.MinValue || value > (double)decimal.MaxValue)

------------- END OF UPDATE

after looking for the definition of the MinValue constant (Update : Using the 'Go to definition' option on visual studio) it seems that the constant does not have the correct value, the constant was declared as below :

> [DecimalConstant(0, 255, 4294967295, 4294967295, 4294967295)]
>   public const decimal MinValue = m;

so I have been curious to see the declaration of this same constraint on the .net framework (UPDATE : Using the 'Go to definition' option on visual studio) which I found completely different :

> [DecimalConstant(0, 128, 4294967295, 4294967295, 4294967295)] 
>   public const decimal MinValue = -79228162514264337593543950335m;

So the solution to my problem may be the replacement of the (double)decimal.MinValue cast by the value of that constant in the .net framework, but i need to be sure that this fix will have no impact on my app ? my be the mobile CPU-registers will not be able to hold a value with this size!

------------------- UPDATE :

 
My developement environnement is : Windows 8.1, Visual Studio 2013 Update 1 and mono-droid v4.10.01073.

------------------- END OF UPDATE

Comment: It's not really clear where you got these two snippets from, or what *your* code is. Can you give a short but complete example which *uses* `decimal.MinValue` but has issues?

Comment: Hi Jon Skeet, thaks for your reply, the code that doesn't work is very simple : if (value < (double)decimal.MinValue || value > (double)decimal.MaxValue). the cast "(double)decimal.MinValue" does not compile with the specified error.

Comment: Hmm. It compiles with `mcs` for me (and csc, unsurprisingly). Which version of Xamarin.Android / Monodroid are you using? (I can try it with a recent version of Xamarin.Android tonight.)

Comment: Hi Jon, sorry for the late of my answer, Stackoverflow have been in readonly, so the version i'm using is mono-android-4.10.01073, my development environnement is : Windows 8 and visual studio 2013 with update 1.

Comment: Hmm... I can find Xamarin.Android 4.10, but not mono-android-4.10. Where are you seeing that version number? And can you update to the latest stable release?

Comment: Hi Jon, we have a Xamarin Entreprise account and we are using it to download the tools from Xamarin, we can't access the support because our account has expired and the renew procedure takes times in my company. after looking on the properties of the MSI by a right click on the msi file and click on the Properties menuitem, on the details tab the specified object is Xamarin.Android 4.10 (4.10.01073) but the file name is mono-android-4.10.01073_signed.msi, so i suppose that just the filename is different from your file ?

Comment: Right, okay - just checking that you weren't on a pre-Xamarin.Android product. I didn't check this last night I'm afraid, but I'll try to do so tonight. (IIRC, I'm on 4.12.)

Comment: Ok Jon, thak's a lot for your help

Comment: funny I just got the same error , I don't depend heavily but I am curious. Very similar settings and code https://github.com/batbuild/duality/blob/master/Duality/Utility/Math/MathF.cs#L88

Answer (score 0):

Reading all your edits and updates, there is absolutely no difference between using the constant `decimal.MinValue` and using the actual value itself. In fact, the compiler will replace all constants with their actual values when compiling your project, so the resulting compiled code is identical.

Comment: Hi Racil, thanks for your replay, the problem is that the compiler does not compile the specified line with 'Invalid decimal constant' error, so i think that the value is not correctly replaced during the compile time.

Comment: @SamirChakour I understand that, but you were asking at the end whether you could hard-code the value `-79228162514264337593543950335m`, and my answer was to that question. Yes you can, and that's identical to using `decimal.MinValue` as the compiler will generate identical results.

Comment: Hi Recil, sorry for my misunderstood and thaks for your answer i'll try that.